# How to download JavaMail (mail.jar) and JAF (activation.jar) using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, jakarta-mail, pom.xml

I want to do this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm about sending emails with java and the first line of the tutorial says that I need to download `JavaMail (mail.jar)` and `JAF (activation.jar)`, and I want to download those jars using maven is that possible since this popular website says that is not possible http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-download-javamail-api-from-maven/ , 
I tried searching in the maven repository but there are too many jars with the same name

Comment: That website just says that the libraries are not in central repository. So they use additional repository `http://download.java.net/maven/2/` (defined in `repositories` tag).

Comment: search for 'maven repository' in google, then you can find your dependencies parameters for many libraries

Answer (score 7):

You simply need to add this dependency to your maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

No need to add `activation` too (unless you want to use a specific version) as it is already a dependency of `javax.mail` such that it will be added as dependency to your project by transitivity.

---

You can find all the artifacts' description in the [home page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) of the `javamail` project.

Comment: Do we still need to set the Windows CLASSPATH (https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#classpath) after we have added the Maven dependency?

Comment: If you intend to launch it outside maven the answer is yes otherwise the answer is no since maven will set it for you

Answer (score 3):

Use the following links to get the required artifacts from the maven central repository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1

**Or**

Add these to your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ok great. i just realized there is a maven repository exist solving out this case.

Answer (score 0):

For people who want the jar file and also the source code for debugging purpose. Download directly from the JavaMail project website.

> https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases